# using awk if to print entire line on first column criteria

Tags: awk

I have a file called test_data.txt and inside the file is the below:

```
20:20:20 test1
20:21:21 test2
20:21:49 test3
20:21:57 test4
20:21:57 test5
20:21:57 test6
20:22:57 test7
20:25:59 test8
20:25:59 test9
20:25:59 test10
20:25:59 test11
20:29:03 test12
20:29:04 test13
20:29:31 test14
```

The 1st column is what I want to search on for example. The 1st column present hours:minutes:seconds (HH:MM:SS). I would like to use variables to pull data for the entire line if the hour and minutes are met:

```
var1=20:20
var2=20:22
cat test_data.txt | awk '{if ($1 == "'"$var1"'" || $1 == "'"$var2"'") print $0;}'
```

Expected output:

```
20:20:20 test1
20:22:57 test7
```

The awk I am using clearly does not work, because I do not want to search on seconds. The below method does work, but how do I use multiple variables in the example:

```
var1=20:20
var2=20:22
ERE='^'$var1':[[:digit:]]+$' <test_data.txt awk '$1 ~ ENVIRON["ERE"]'
```

I am not sure if the above can handle multiple variables in the same command as one

Output from above command:

```
20:20:20 test1
```

Comment: `~` matching, unlike `==`, doesn't have to be total, ERE supports disjunction, and an awk var is easier than an envvar: `<file awk -v ere="^(20:20|20:22)" '$0~ere'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass multiple HH:MM values into awk as a space-separated string, and then break that into an array in the awk BEGIN block. Then for each record of the data file, test if $1 starts with one of the HH:MM strings.

```bash
awk -v times="20:20 20:22" '
  BEGIN {n = split(times, t)}
  {for (i=1; i<=n; i++) if (index($1, t[i]) == 1) {print; break}}
' test_data.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on some of [@glennjacman's code](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/725176/133219) - you could create a hash table from the target times and use a hash lookup on the input values for efficiency:

```
awk -v times="20:20 20:22" '
    BEGIN {
        split(times, tmp)
        for ( i in tmp ) {
            t[tmp[i]]
        }
        FS = ":"
    }
    ($1 FS $2) in t
' test_data.txt
20:20:20 test1
20:22:57 test7
```